# Escape Special Char in Property file

Tags: java, velocity

In Velocity property file how to escape special chars like `comma` and `space`.

```
prop.put("file.resource.loader.path",
        "C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Velocity-ECnet/templates1, "+
        "C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Velocity-ECnet/comma, templates2");


Velocity.init(prop);
```

problem is it reads templates inside of

Folder 1 : `templates1` 
but not inside of Folder 2: `comma, templates2` .

*File* `comma_template.vm` present inside of  *Folder* `comma, templates2`

[image]

Error :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException:
 Unable to find resource 'comma_template.vm'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make sure all the names match (`template1` sometimes has an `s`). Also: Do you want to look Velocity into the folder `comma, templates` or into the folders `comma` and `templates` (and there is a 2 missing as well).

Comment: Thanks for reply.Sorry for typo,please find the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity will split the path at `,`. It can't recognize that you have a folder which contains a comma in the name, so it sees three paths:

```
 C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Velocity-ECnet/templates1
 C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Velocity-ECnet/comma
 templates2
```

To solve this, you have to rename the folder - avoid spaces and commas.

An alternate soltion might be to use `URLResourceLoader`. Then you could encode illegal characters:

```
"file:///C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Velocity-ECnet/templates1, "+
    "file:///C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Velocity-ECnet/comma%2c%20templates2"
```